# creatreactapp & Reflux TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function

Tags: reactjs, refluxjs

I have a simple createreactapp that I want to test reflux with, instead of redux, and I'm trying to include Reflux into it. I checked the spelling of .Component and .Store and class structure but still.

When I run it it gives me this error:

TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function.

is reflux just too old for createreactapp?
is it a webpack error?
babel?

Full error:

```
inherits.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a 
function
    at _inherits (inherits.js:4)
    at statStore.js:7
    at Module../src/statStore.js (statStore.js:7)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:782)
    at fn (bootstrap:150)
    at Module../src/Compass.js (index.css:8)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:782)
    at fn (bootstrap:150)
    at Module../src/index.js (index.css?02e3:45)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:782)
    at fn (bootstrap:150)
    at Object.0 (statStore.js:42)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:782)
    at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
    at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32)
    at main.chunk.js:1
```

**stateStore.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import actions from './actions';
import Reflux from 'reflux';



class statStore extends Reflux.Store {


    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            status:0
        }
        this.listenables = actions;




    }


    onStateUpdate2(){

        this.setState({status:2})
        console.log('stateupdate2')
    }


    onStateUpdate3(){

        this.setState({status:3})
        console.log('stateupdate3')
    }




}


export default statStore;
```

**compass.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import actions from './actions';
import statStore from './statStore';
import Reflux from 'reflux';


class Compass extends Reflux.Component {



    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        //this.store = statStore;
    }





    render(){


        console.log('BAHAHHA')

        return(<div onClick={actions.stateUpdate2}>{this.state.status}</div>)



    }



}


export default Compass;
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import Compass from './Compass';


ReactDOM.render(<Compass />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 0):

yes uhmm I actually deleted the serviceWorker from createreactapp and that was the cause.